# Why is context inside non-interactive Function object different in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval, require, anonymous-function

I'd like to create a function from string that requires another module (don't ask).

When I try to do that in node interactive shell, everything is fine and dandy:

```
> f = new Function("return require('crypto')");
[Function]
> f.call()
{ Credentials: [Function: Credentials],
  (...)
  prng: [Function] }
```

However, when I put the exact same code in file, I am told that require function is not avaliable:

```
israfel:apiary almad$ node test.coffee 

undefined:2
return require('crypto')
       ^
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval at <anonymous> (/tmp/test.coffee:1:67)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/test.coffee:2:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

How to fix that?

Also, it tells me I do not know something about node.js contexts/scopes. What is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is scope.

The argument to `new Function()` is being evaluated in the global scope. Node, however, only defines `require` as a global for its interactive mode/shell. Otherwise, it executes each module within a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) where `require`, `module`, `exports`, etc. are defined as local variables.

So, to define the function so that `require` is in scope ([closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)), you'll have to use the [`function` operator/keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function):

```
f = function () { return require('crypto'); }
```

Or, the [`->` operator](http://coffeescript.org/#literals) in CoffeeScript:

```
f = -> require 'crypto'
```

Comment: So there is no way to execute Function instance in a global scope?

Comment: @Almad You can define a global reference to the function, `f`. But, the body of the function has to be evaluated within the closure to have `require` in scope.