# In Node, how do I require files inside eval?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval, require

I have two files `test.js` and `x.js`, in the same directory:

- `test.js`:

  ```
  console.log(eval( "require('x.js')" ));
  ```
- `x.js` is empty.

**Expected**: `require` returns `undefined`, so nothing is logged.

**Actual**: `node test.js` gives me `Error: Cannot find module 'x.js'` (stack-trace omitted for brevity).

The situation sounds similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263104/why-is-context-inside-non-interactive-function-object-different-in-node-js), with the differences that I've used `eval` rather than `new Function`, and `require` *is* defined, just working unexpectedly.

---

Why is this?

How do I correctly `require` a module in `eval`'d code?

Comment: Obligatory "inb4 eval is evil": I *do* have Very Good Reasons™—I'm writing a lisp macro system that needs the compiler at run-time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To `require()` a local file/module, the path should [start with `.` (same directory) or `..` (parent directory)](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules):

```
console.log(eval( "require('./x.js')" ));
```

Without either of those, Node looks for `x.js` to be a [core module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules) or [contained in a `node_modules` directory](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

---

Unless `eval` is referenced indirectly:

```
var e = eval;           // global eval
e("require('./x.js')"); // ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

It should evaluate the string within the current scope and be able to reference `require`.

Comment: How to require stylus global module?